# permit a user to access only selected directory on the server, via ftp

Tags: ftp, directory, public-folders

i have this folder/subdomain structure on my server:

```
--- website.com
    --- sub.website.com
    --- sub2.website.com
    --- sub3.website.com
```

if i login via sftp with my admin user i can see every folder.
i just created a ‘myuser’ and via ftp it can view his /home/myuser folder.

what’s the best way to permit it to also view sub2.website.com and sub3.website.com?
i'm using ubuntu as my server.
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use file system acl (man setfacl for details) so that the owner can give read/execute access to these directory to myuser

http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/setfacl1.html

please let me know if you want more help.